# $n \mid k^2 \land n+1 \mid l^3 \land n+2 \mid m^4 \to n=?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find three consecutive integers such that the first is divisible by a square, the second one is divisible by a cubic and the third is divisible by a fourth power.

Comment: I guess you want to exclude 1 as a square, a cubic, and a fourth power?

Comment: The smallest solution is $350, 351, 352$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want any 3 consecutive integers with these properties, then you can simply take $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}, n+1  \equiv 0 \pmod{27}$ and $n+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{625}$ and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

This will not give you a very small solution, but using the moduli in a more sensible order (25, 27, 16) i.e. $n \equiv 0 \pmod{25}, n+1  \equiv 0 \pmod{27}$ and $n+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{16}$ gives a reasonably small solution: $350, 351, 352$.

Comment: Is there any way to recognize the more sensible order aside from trying them all?

Comment: Well, we want a power of 2, a power of 3 and a power of 5 which are (in some order) a square, a cube and a fourth power. The simplistic solution is to take 4, 27 and 625, but this gives rather large value for the product of all three. So we need to choose powers which minimises the product. The easiest way is to try to make the 3 powers as nearly equal as possible, and the best way is 25, 27, 16 - pretty much by "inspection", although it seems "obvious" that taking the powers decreasing as the bases increase will almost certainly do just that.

Comment: I was thinking more about the order to take them in.  I agree that $16,25,27$ are good powers to use, but that leaves six choices of what order they should come in.  You could also do $n \equiv 0 \pmod {16}, n+1\equiv 0 \pmod {25}, n+2 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$

Comment: I thought my previous comment explained that - take the indices in reverse order to the bases, and that should approximately equalise the values (16, 25, 27) thus minimising the product of them.

Comment: If I do $n \equiv 0 \pmod {25}, n+1\equiv 0 \pmod {16}, n+2 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$, because I can do the first and third with $25$, I get $1375$ for a final solution, a bit larger.

Comment: Maybe I was just lucky. I certainly didn't try all the possibilities, and couldn't see a simple/precise way to get to the minimum solution quickly.